# Accessing the filepath using ajax call via JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, file-upload

I've a file upload control in ASPX page that will only accept excel file. If the correct file is posted to the control, that file path will be send via a jQuery Ajax call to a web service. My web service will perform some calculation on the excel file and save that file locally.

I run this project successfully in Visual Studio Development Sever. But when I deployed it on my production server, that file path is causing an error because it check that file locally in the production server. How can I overcome this issue?

Here my jQuery ajax function :

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ExcelUpload.asmx/FillObjets",
            data: JSON.stringify({ fileName: filename }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#Status").html("<br><center><img src=images/ajax-loader.gif/></center>");
            },
            success: function (msg) {
            var output="";
             var re = eval('(' + msg.d + ')');
                  if (re.length > 0) {
                      for (var i in re) {
                         var xl = re[i];
                         switch(parseInt(xl.status))
                         {
                            case 1: output=xl.message;break; 
                            case 2: output=xl.message;break;
                         }                          
                      }
                   $("#Status").html(output);
                }


            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Which filepath are you trying to access? The one on the client computer?

Comment: yes in the client computer.thanks

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons you cannot access the full filepath to the file that was selected in a file input on the client browser. You can only access the filename but not its location.

Comment: ok. but at the run time, can i access the file and save it to root directory using jquery?

Comment: @ArooranS, where do you want to access this file? On the server? Bear in mind that you cannot upload files using AJAX. You could use some of the file upload javascript controls out there such as Uploadify.

Comment: Why would this cause to fail on production, but not on Development Sever? I don't think this is the issue. Eitherway, only the file name is sent and not the full path..

Comment: @Darin if I get the filename, then how i can i save the file into a root folder?

Comment: @ArooranS, you can't. You will need to upload the file to the server. And as I said, you cannot do this using AJAX.